# Why parentheses are not required when partial function used as parameter in scala?

Tags: scala

I found that parentheses are not required when partial function used as parameter in Scala

```
val array = Array(2)

array.map(x => x + 1)
array.map { case x => x + 1 }
```

`{ case x => x + 1 }` defines a partial function here, so it should be `array.map({ case x => x + 1 })`, but there are no parentheses.So what happend here? what syntactic is here?

Comment: Parentheses are used to define code block and case it self defines a code block so why do we need parentheses there. And if you see both or your lines it has difference that one has only once line and second has defining the partial function.

Comment: It is not clear what kind of an answer different from "yes, it is a syntactic sugar" you expect?

Comment: curly braces are used to define code block, AFAIK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in the language specification. The syntax for [function applications](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#function-applications) is this:

```
SimpleExpr    ::=  SimpleExpr1 ArgumentExprs
ArgumentExprs ::=  ‘(’ [Exprs] ‘)’
                |  ‘(’ [Exprs ‘,’] PostfixExpr ‘:’ ‘_’ ‘*’ ‘)’
                |  [nl] BlockExpr
Exprs         ::=  Expr {‘,’ Expr}
```

So the arguments to a function can be one or more expressions surrounded by `(` `)`, or a single `BlockExpr` if the function takes a single argument.

Moving on the section about [blocks](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#blocks) we find this:

```
BlockExpr  ::=  ‘{’ CaseClauses ‘}’
             |  ‘{’ Block ‘}’
Block      ::=  BlockStat {semi BlockStat} [ResultExpr]
```

Partial functions are defined using the `CaseClauses` option, so they must be surrounded by `{` `}` to make a block expression. This block expression is then a valid argument for a function with a single parameter.

Functions that take multiple parameters must always use `(` `)`.